# SFINAE inside std::enable_if argument

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, c++17, enable-if

I have different *view* types, which each have a `std::size_t View::dimension` member constant, and a `typename View::value_type` member type.

The following compile-type check should verify if both `From` and `To` are views (verified using `is_view<>`), and the content of `From` can be assigned to `To`. (same dimensions, and convertible value types).

```
template<typename From, typename To>
struct is_compatible_view : std::integral_constant<bool,
    is_view<From>::value &&
    is_view<To>::value &&
    From::dimension == To::dimension &&
    std::is_convertible<typename From::value_type, typename To::value_type>::value
> { };
```

`is_view<T>` is such that it always evaluates to `std::true_type` or  `std::false_type`, for any type `T`. The problem is that if `From` or `To` is not a view type, then `From::dimension` (for example) may not exist, and `is_compatible_view<From, To>` causes a compilation error.
It should instead evaluate to `std::false_type` in this case.

`is_compatible_view` is used for SFINAE with `std::enable_if`, to disable member functions. For example a view class can have a member function

```
struct View {
    constexpr static std::size_t dimension = ...
    using value_type = ...

    template<typename Other_view>
    std::enable_if_t<is_compatible_view<Other_view, View>> assign_from(const Other_view&);

    void assign_from(const Not_a_view&);
};
```

`Not_a_view` is not a view, and causes a compilation error in `is_compatible_view<Not_a_view, ...>`. When calling `view.assign_from(Not_a_view())`, SFINAE does not apply, and instead a compilation error occurs when the compiler tries to resolve the first `assign_from` function.

How can `is_compatible_view` be written such that this works correctly? In C++17 does `std::conjunction<...>` allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is using something like `std::conditional` to delay evaluation of some parts of your type trait until we've verified that other parts of your type trait are already true.

That is:

```
// this one is only valid if From and To are views
template <class From, class To>
struct is_compatible_view_details : std::integral_constant<bool,
    From::dimension == To::dimension &&
    std::is_convertible<typename From::value_type, typename To::value_type>::value
> { };        

// this is the top level one
template<typename From, typename To>
struct is_compatible_view : std::conditional_t<
    is_view<From>::value && is_view<To>::value,
    is_compatible_view_details<From, To>,
    std::false_type>::type
{ };
```

Note that I'm using both `conditional_t` and `::type`. `is_compatible_view_details` will only be instantiated if both `From` and `To` are views.

---

A similar approach would be to use `std::conjunction` with the above, which because of short-circuiting will similarly delay evaluation:

```
template <class From, class To>
struct is_compatible_view : std::conjunction_t<
    is_view<From>,
    is_view<To>,
    is_compatible_view_details<From, To>
    >
{ };
```

Either way, you need to pull out the details.

---

A third approach would be to use `enable_if_t` as a specialization:

```
template <class From, class To, class = void>
struct is_compatible_view : std::false_type { };

template <class From, class To>
struct is_compatible_view<From, To, std::enable_if_t<
    is_view<From>::value &&
    is_view<To>::value &&
    From::dimension == To::dimension &&
    std::is_convertible<typename From::value_type, typename To::value_type>::value>>
: std::true_type { };
```

Here, if any of the expressions in the `enable_if_t` are ill-formed, SFINAE kicks in and we just use the primary template, which is `false_type`.

Comment: I actually don't really see the point of the `::type` in your first snippet. Also, depending on the use case, it may suffice to make an `enable_if_compatible_view` alias template which just pull any errors in `From::value_type` etc. into the immediate context.